# Stochastic average of a differential equation is not the same as average of its solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, average, stochastic-differential-equations

Assume a static (time-independent) random variable $r$ for which we know its probability distribution $P(r)$. Consider this to be a Gaussian distribution, such that $\langle r \rangle=0$ and $\langle r^2 \rangle=r_0$, etc.

Consider now the following differential equation: $\frac{d}{dt}X(t)=r A X(t)$, where $X=(x_1,x_2)^T$ and $A$ is a time-independent $2\times 2$ matrix.

I am interested in taking the average of the differential equation over the random variable.

If I naively just take the expected value of the previous differential equation, the problem is that I would just get $\frac{d}{dt}X=0$ because $\langle r \rangle=0$. This is not true, as $X$ is a functional of r, $X(r,t)$, so $\langle r X(r,t) \rangle\neq0$.

One possible solution would be to formally solve the differential equation as $X(t)=e^{rAt}X(0)$ and then take the average. I would like to avoid this method, as it is not always aplicable.

What would be the correct way to proceed if I would like to get an averaged differential equation that properly reproduces the results of averaging the solution?

Note: I know about Novikov's theorem which is sometimes used to solve such stochastic differential equations using two-time correlation functions. However, as far as I am aware, it only works if the stochastic variable is dynamical, i.e. r(t) is sampled by the solution of a stochastic differential equation. In my case, my stochastic variable is static, so only the probability distribution is known.

Comment: The problem is $X$ depends on $r$, so $X(r,t)$ is a random variable and then you can *not* have $\mathbb{E}(rAX) = 0$. You have instead  $\mathbb{E}(rAX) = A\cdot\mathbb{E}(rX)$ which is less likely to be $0$.

Comment: @NN2 I see... what would be then the right procedure to average the diff. equation?

Comment: I don't know whether there exists a different method than the one you had already.

Comment: Are you speaking of only linear evolution equations? In the most general case I doubt much can be said. In your case you could write down the formal solution and expand it's expectation in terms of the moments of $r$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider linear evolution equations of the form

$$\tag{1}
x'(t)=r A x(t)
$$

Where $x$ is an $n$-tuple, $r$ is a scalar random variable and $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. The solution of (1) (which we will not need to evaluate) is

$$\tag{2}
x(t)=e^{rAt}x(0)
$$

You seek a differential equation for the average $\tilde{x}$ such that

$$\tag{3}
\tilde{x}(t):=\left< x(t) \right>=\left< e^{rAt}\right>x(0)
$$

with initial conditions $\tilde{x}(0)=x(0)$. Differentiating (3) we have

$$\tag{4}
\tilde{x}'(t)=K'(t)\tilde{x}(t)
$$

Where $e^{K(t)}=\left< e^{rAt}\right>$ is a 'matrix cumulant' generating function. The appropriate mean-field equivalent of (1) is obtained by making the replacement $rA\to K'(t)$. For Gaussian $r$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, we can evaluate explicitly

$$\tag{5}
K(t)=\mu t A +\frac{\sigma^2 t^2}{2}A^2
$$

Which follows from expanding the exponential and integrating each term against the Gaussian measure. The evolution equations for the averages of (1) are

$$\tag{6}
\tilde{x}'(t)=\left[\mu  +\sigma^2 A  t \right]A  \tilde{x}(t)
$$

From which we see that, at the level of the differential equation, the 'average' $r$ corresponds to $\tilde{r}(t)=\mu+\sigma^2A t$.

Notes:

1. In the case when $A=A(t)$, equation (2) needs to replaced by the [ordered exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_exponential?useskin=vector) $x(t)=\mathcal{T} [e^{r \int_0^t dt' A(t')}]x(0)$, and the analogues of (4) through (6) will become more complicated.
2. If $r=r(t)$ is a $\delta$ correlated process, a result similar to (6) holds, which can be obtained from the result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4727779/probability-density-function-pdf-of-a-wiener-process/4748732#4748732).
3. If $r$ is not normally distributed, it is still not necessary to evaluate $\left<e^{rAt}\right>$. Instead, the (scalar) cumulants $\kappa_m$ of $r$ maybe be inserted directly into (1) to obtain (6) via the replacement $rA \to \frac{d}{dt}\sum_m \frac{\kappa_m t^mA^m}{m!}$

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful about how you consider this ODE. A reasonable interpretation is a path-by-path interpretation. That is, for each $\omega \in \Omega$ we can define the differential equation:
$$\frac{dX_t}{dt}(\omega ) = r(\omega) A X_t$$
whose solution is the trajectory $$X_t(\omega) = X_0 \exp \left( r(\omega) A t \right)$$
One can then compute the time-average as:

$$\mu_t = E(X_t) = E( X_0 \exp \left( r A t \right))$$

where the expectation is taken relative to the distribution of $r$.

Novikov's criterion gives you conditions under which a certain process is a martingale, but that process has nothing to do with your random ODE.

Comment: You are right, and this is the interpretation I have. I can compute the time-average $\mu_t$ you define without problem. My main question is, how can one do the same on the level of the ODE such that we get an averaged-ODE whose result is $\mu_t$?.

Comment: @J.Agusti at the level of the ODE you would need to understand the dependence between $r$ and $X$, as $X$ is also a random variable. The derivative of the path is a stochastic process itself with $\frac{dX_t}{dt} (\omega) = Ar(\omega)X_t(\omega)$. Its expectation is then $A E(rX_t) = A E(r X_0 e^{rAt})$.

Comment: @J.Agusti in particular, for this particular ODE, you end up computing an analytical path-by-path solution to actually be able to compute the expectation. For general $\frac{dX}{dt} = f(\omega. t. X_t)$ you cannot say anything without understanding $f$ and how it forces a dependence between $r$ and $X$,

Comment: I am not sure about how one can compute the analytical path-by-path solution for my problem. Do you have any reference on this? If I understand your 1st comment, we need to solve something like $E[\frac{dX_t}{dt}(\omega)]=AE[r X_t]=AE[r X_0e^{r A t}]$, right? The second identity seems a bit circular... I need the formal solution to be put inside the ODE to solve it. And if so, how does one even solve this equation?

Comment: @J.Agusti why is it circular? You've given us an ODE. which we agree should be interpreted path-by-path, we've solved it and used it to compute the expectation of the derivative by substituting in the solution. Imagine you had the deterministic ODE $\frac{dy}{dt} = y$ whose solution is $y = y_0 e^t$. There is nothing circular about writing $\frac{dy}{dt}= y = y_0e^t$ and calling this your derivative.

Comment: There is no general recipe for dealing with this sort of thing, you need some kind of "commutator" which is problem-dependent. The whole discipline of mean field theory is essentially about this kind of thing, but in the setting of dimension reduction.

Comment: @Ian could you give me more information about this 'commutator'?

Comment: It's an analogy to the situation with linear operators: you have $x=(t,x_0,r)$, you want $E[F(t,x_0,r)]$ where $E$ is expectation and $F$ is the time evolution operator, you want to exchange them, but you don't expect $E \circ F$ and $F \circ E$ to be the same. When they're linear mappings from a space to itself, you have a "commutator" $E \circ F - F \circ E$ which in general isn't just zero (unless the operators commute).

Comment: @J.Agusti it would be helpful if you could state what kind of random ODE you are interested in. Why do you say "I would like to avoid this method, as it is not always applicable."? It certainly is applicable for the ODE you stated, but if you're interested in more general ODEs, nothing more can be said.